# Bootstrap 'select' styling, using jquery to transform into bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

First things first, I've created a select list to choose an option, when an option has been selected additional info displays below using the bootstrap accordion component. see how it works here - http://bootply.com/69516

So the above works how I want it too, however it looks pretty rubbish - ideally I want it to look like the bootstrap dropdown box. I found some jquery to do this(below) and here is the bootply fork with the jquery inserted - http://bootply.com/69518

Unfortunately, it does not work, I a guessing the transformation removes the "value" fields originally in the select list. I can get by with jquery however still learning and this is just too much for me!

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('select').each(function(i, e){
        if (!($(e).data('convert') == 'no')) {                                                    
            $(e).hide().wrap('<div class="btn-group" id="select-group-' + i + '" />');
            var select = $('#select-group-' + i);
            var current = ($(e).val()) ? $(e).val(): '&nbsp;';         
            select.html('<input type="hidden" value="' + $(e).val() + '" name="' + $(e).attr('name') + '" id="' + $(e).attr('id') + '" class="' + $(e).attr('class') + '" /><a class="btn" href="javascript:;">' + current + '</a><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;"><span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>');                                   
            $(e).find('option').each(function(o,q) {
                select.find('.dropdown-menu').append('<li><a href="javascript:;" data-value="' + $(q).attr('value') + '">' + $(q).text() + '</a></li>');                    
                    if ($(q).attr('selected'))
                        select.find('.dropdown-menu li:eq(' + o + ')').click();
            });
            select.find('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
                select.find('input[type=hidden]').val($(this).data('value')).change();
                select.find('.btn:eq(0)').text($(this).text());
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look: http://gustavohenke.github.io/bselect - it's not soo complete, but maybe help you. And unfornately it haves almostly no docs yet :(

Comment: Yes looked at this previously, the drop down menu didn't work and required a lot more files etc... The above seems simpler, however can't get the two parts to work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bootply.com/69711 - Could not merge the two scripts together so had to style it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end of

```
$('select[name="panel"]').change(function(event){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var value = selected.attr("value");
    var name=  $(this).attr("name");
    var selector = '[for-field="'+name+'"]';
    $('.accordion-body'+selector).addClass('collapse');
    var selectorForValue = selector+'[for-value="'+value+'"]';
    var selectedPanel = $('.accordion-body'+ selectorForValue  );
    selectedPanel.removeClass('collapse');
})
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple!

Comment: Latest bootply - http://bootply.com/69683 unfortunately still cant get the info to appear.